# Get notification for all cell changes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get a notification for all cell updates in excel.
My current code is something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ...
End Sub
```

My problem is, that it only runs when a direct cell change happens. If I modify a cell, some other cells might change if their values relies on the modified cell. 
Is there a way to detect these changes too? I would like to avoid the mirror copy method.

Comment: You can look at Precedents/Dependants, which shows what you need.   So you'd need to look at the cells dependants, but not sure what the end goal is?  Or you could look at someway of using the formula, broken down to cell addresses, could get into difficulty with formulae like if(b1="B1",x,y)....

Comment: I would like to put special formatting in all of the modified rows. I hoped that there is another event handler or something for these, but this solution is also very simple, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will allow you to access all cells containing formulae which depend upon `Target`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    ...
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In Target.Dependents
        ' Do something
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0
    ...
End Sub
```

The `On Error Resume Next` statement is necessary because the loop will throw an error if there are no dependent cells.

You may also want to call `Application.Calculate` before that `For Each` loop  in order to force re-calculation of those cells.